# How to design Cassandra Scheme for User Actions Log?

Tags: mysql, cassandra, cql

I have a table like this in MYSQL to log user actions :

```
CREATE TABLE `actions` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `module` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `controller` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `action` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `date` Timestamp NOT NULL,
    `userid` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `ip` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `duration` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

I have a MYSQL Query Like this to find out count of specific actions per day :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actions WHERE actions.action = "join" AND 
YEAR(date)=2017 AND MONTH(date)=06 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), 
DAY(date)
```

this takes 50 - 60 second to me to have a list of days with count of "join" action with only 5 million rows and index in date and action.

So, I want to log actions using Cassandra, so How can I design Cassandra scheme and How to query to get such request less than 1 second.

Comment: Would you want the same data once the data grows... like for how many years and month you need data... for one year it will give max 365 rows

Comment: think I want to give rows for specific day in a year,

Comment: is it something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actions WHERE actions.action = "join" and date='2017-06-30'`? OR `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actions WHERE actions.action = "join" AND YEAR(date)=2017 AND MONTH(date)=06 GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)`.... if you can give your exact query requirement it might help in data modelling

Comment: @undefined_variable: thanks, my query is exactly like number two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    id timeuuid,
    module varchar,
    controller varchar,
    action varchar,
    date_time timestamp,
    userid bigint,
    ip varchar,
    duration double,
    year int,
    month int,
    dt date,
    PRIMARY KEY ((action,year,month),dt,id)
);
```

Explanation:
With abobe table Defination

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actions WHERE actions.action = "join" AND yaer=2017 AND month=06 GROUP BY action,year,month,dt`

will hit single partition.
In `dt` column only date will be there... may be you can change it to only day number with `int` as datatype and since `id` is `timeuuid`.. it will be unique.

**Note:** GROUP BY is supported by cassandra 3.10 and above

Comment: special thanks, just a question, should I use id timeuuid ? is it useful in future ... ?

Comment: yes.. it will create unique id... if you  don't include some uniqueness in your primary key.. data will be overwritten